# How to get row values with DataGridTemplateColumn connected to different ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I’m using WPF MVVM DataGrid and one of the columns is the equivalent of DataGridComboBoxColumn, but made of DataGridTemplateColumn .
DataGrid itself is binded to one object, and ComboBox column is binded to the separate one.

The XAML code is:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemNamesSetting}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item1" Binding="{Binding Path=OriginalItemName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item2" Binding="{Binding Path=FinalItemName}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Attribute">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AttributesBindingList, ElementName=ThirdStepTab}" DisplayMemberPath="PropName" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item3" Binding="{Binding Path=Separatopr}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The question is how can I get the full row data? I’m planning to have one “Save” button that would send data to the database and I need to get data in text columns + data at ComboBox from different ource – row by row. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to take data from UI, it binded to your properties....

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `SelectedItem` property of `DataGrid` to your MVVM view Model. Also, the one of relevant property of view model should bind to Combobox `SelectedValue`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemNamesSetting}" SelectedItem="{Binding VMPropertyName}" >
      <DataGrid.Columns >
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item1" Binding="{Binding Path=OriginalItemName}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item2" Binding="{Binding Path=FinalItemName}" />                                        
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Attribute">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AttributesBindingList, ElementName=ThirdStepTab}" DisplayMemberPath="PropName" SelectedValue="{Binding PropertyOfVM}"  />
               </DataTemplate>                           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item3" Binding="{Binding Path=Separatopr}" />
```